# How to properly use formGroupName in Angular forms

Tags: angular, forms, firebase, angular-forms

### How do I correctly use the formGroupName inside a reactive form in Angular?

I'm not able to populate the data returned from Firebase on my form.

You are correctly saving the data in the CloudFirestore, creating an array for address with values ​​inside.

At the moment I'm doing the following:

**myform.model.ts:**

```
export class People {
    name: string;
    city: string;
    postal_code: string;

constructor(data?) {

   data = data || {}; // added this line

         // before executing the subscribe is coming undefined
         // and when I try to access data.adress.postal_code
         // there is an error saying that postal_code is undefined

         // is passing here twice, the first time comes undefined

         console.log (data.adress.postal_code); // undefined

         this.name = data.name || '';
         this.city = data.adress.city || '';
        this.postal_code = data.adress.postal_code || '';
}

}
```

**myform.component.ts:**

```
pageType: string;

people = new People();
onFormChanged: Subscription;
form: FormGroup;

ngOnInit() {
    // Subscribe to update form on changes
    this.onFormChanged =
        this.formService.onFormChanged
            .subscribe(data => {

                // firebase return
                if (data) {
                    this.people= new People(data);
                    this.pageType = 'edit';
                }
                else {
                    this.pageType = 'add';
                    this.people = new People();
                }

                this.form = this.createForm();
            });
}

createForm() {
    return this.formBuilder.group({
        name: [this.people.name, Validators.required],

        adress: this.formBuilder.group({
            postal_code: [this.people.postal_code],
            city: [this.people.city],
        }),
    });
}
```

**myform.component.html:**

```
<form name="form" [formGroup]="form">

<div fxLayout="row" fxLayout.xs="column" fxLayoutAlign="start">
    <mat-form-field fxFlex="20">
       <input matInput name="name" placeholder="Name" formControlName="name" required>
    </mat-form-field>
</div>

<div fxLayout="row" fxLayout.xs="column" fxLayoutAlign="start">

    <mat-form-field fxFlex="20" formGroupName="adress">
        <input matInput name="city" placeholder="City" formControlName="city">
    </mat-form-field>

    <mat-form-field fxFlex="20" formGroupName="adress">
        <input matInput name="postal_code" placeholder="Postal code" formControlName="postal_code">
    </mat-form-field>

</div>

</form>
```

The data returned from the firebase is:

```
{name: 'Person 1', adress: {city: 'City 1', postal_code: '2348917'}}
```

Just fill in name ... City and Zip code is not filling, What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You only need to use the `formGroupName` once:

```
<div fxLayout="row" fxLayout.xs="column" fxLayoutAlign="start" formGroupName="adress">

    <mat-form-field fxFlex="20" >
        <input matInput name="city" placeholder="City" formControlName="city">
    </mat-form-field>

    <mat-form-field fxFlex="20">
        <input matInput name="postal_code" placeholder="Postal code" formControlName="postal_code">
    </mat-form-field>

</div>
```

and in your model constructor you need to access the `adress` property before you can access `city` or `postal_code`:

```
    constructor(data?) {
   this.name = dataname || '';
   this.city = data.adress.city || '';
   this.postal_code = data.adress.postal_code || '';
}
```

Comment: Are you sure that `{name: 'Person 1', adress: {city: 'City 1', postal_code: '2348917'}}` is the object you're getting and that `adress` isn't really `address` in the object? (address being the correct spelling)

Comment: For this I need to change the myform.model.ts right?

Comment: Shoot I scrolled past that and was looking at the code below, I didn't see your model code! It's the constructor

Comment: I am putting the values referring to the address inside of adress, because this form will get very big ... the adress key contains an object with the values referent ... this is exactly how it is returned from the firebase ...

Comment: In your constructor add `this.city = data.adress.city || '';` See the updated answer.

Comment: I am having another problem, please check myform.model.ts ... I changed the way it is

Comment: Just to be clear, updating your constructor solved the first problem, right? Now you're having an issue with the subscription to the observable?

Comment: Yes it has been solved, now I am having problem in constructor ... it is passed by the constructor twice ... the first time `data.adress.postal_code` is coming undefined because it has not received reply from subscribe ... How can I deal with this to not occur error? I've done a treatment with if, but I'm having duplicity in my code and I do not want this ...

Comment: If you're getting undefined first, followed by the data in your subscription callback then you're probably trying to access the property before the callback is complete. StackOverflow protocol is to keep one question per post. If you create another question with that issue and code I (and other people) will be able to answer it there.